# Control naming of Cache Keys for cached views

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I'm caching views in my Django project.

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def view_to_cache
```

Because users can edit the content, I'd like to delete specific caches when a user makes an edit. To do this, I'll `cache.delete(KEY)` at the end of the edit function.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to get the value of the appropriate key to delete.

I ran memcached_stats to get the keys, and they're all random. Any idea how I'd know what key to delete?  Here's a sample of the cache:

```
>>> from memcached_stats import MemcachedStats
>>> mem = MemcachedStats()
>>> mem.stats()
{'auth_cmds': '0', 'reclaimed': '0', 'pid': '67140', 'cas_hits': '0', 'uptime': '3075', 'delete_misses': '0', 'listen_disabled_num': '0', 'cas_misses': '0', 'decr_hits': '0', 'incr_hits': '0', 'version': '1.4.5', 'limit_maxbytes': '67108864', 'bytes_written': '13604', 'incr_misses': '0', 'accepting_conns': '1', 'rusage_system': '0.073969', 'total_items': '13', 'cmd_get': '26', 'curr_connections': '12', 'threads': '4', 'total_connections': '33', 'cmd_set': '13', 'curr_items': '9', 'conn_yields': '0', 'get_misses': '7', 'bytes_read': '24226', 'cas_badval': '0', 'cmd_flush': '0', 'evictions': '0', 'bytes': '19492', 'connection_structures': '14', 'auth_errors': '0', 'rusage_user': '0.063413', 'time': '1327784334', 'delete_hits': '1', 'pointer_size': '64', 'decr_misses': '0', 'get_hits': '19'}
>>> mem.keys()
[':1:django.contrib.sessions.cachec7a594602214b4992c53575b3eda010d', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..511894add8326666c1a436bdb37e50ce.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..642ae686efc6dbc27b334fc0e1d22641.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..7739f0feb4375839a76f5cae2d10a69c.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..e32e41ea17bca494f9794fa87f5ec0d6.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.511894add8326666c1a436bdb37e50ce.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.642ae686efc6dbc27b334fc0e1d22641.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.7739f0feb4375839a76f5cae2d10a69c.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us', ':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.e32e41ea17bca494f9794fa87f5ec0d6.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us']
>>> cache.has_key(':1:django.contrib.sessions.cachec7a594602214b4992c53575b3eda010d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cache' is not defined
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.has_key(':1:django.contrib.sessions.cachec7a594602214b4992c53575b3eda010d')
False
>>> cache.has_key('1:django.contrib.sessions.cachec7a594602214b4992c53575b3eda010d')
False
>>> cache.has_key('django.contrib.sessions.cachec7a594602214b4992c53575b3eda010d')
True
>>> cache.has_key('views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.e32e41ea17bca494f9794fa87f5ec0d6.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en-us')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not random, they are md5 hashes of the URL. There is a `get_cache_key` in `django.utils.cache` which can use or look at to recreate the keys. It accepts a request object and I think it uses `request.path` and `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`.